# Find an inhabitant for type $\phi$

Tags: lambda-calculus, intuitionistic-logic

I am studying from Sorensen's book (Lectures on the Curry-Howard isomorphism, ed. 2006) and there is a type that is said to be inhabited, but I need to find the inhabitant. However, I can't find it.  The type is:
$$\phi=[(a\rightarrow b)\rightarrow q]\rightarrow q$$ with $a=(p\rightarrow q)\rightarrow r$, $b=(p\rightarrow r)\rightarrow r$ and $p,q,r$ any variables.

Starting from what I want, I thought that I need some term $\lambda x^{(a\rightarrow b)\rightarrow q}.xN^{a\rightarrow b}$. If I keep up with abstractions I find it hard to mix the variables so that I have a term $\lambda x^{(a\rightarrow b)\rightarrow q}.x\lambda y^{a}\lambda z^{p \rightarrow r}B^r$ for some $B$ (i.e. to find a suitable $B$). So I think there must be an application (or more applications) in the term $N^{a\rightarrow b}$.

I am using the above as an example to explain what troubles me. I don't really want a solution, but some **advice** on how to proceed with searching for the inhabitant (if any) for a given type **in general**.

I have seen an example in the book where $\psi=(((((p\rightarrow q)\rightarrow p)\rightarrow p)\rightarrow q)\rightarrow q)$ is inhabited by $\lambda x^{(((p\rightarrow q)\rightarrow p)\rightarrow p)\rightarrow q}.x(\lambda y^{(p\rightarrow q)\rightarrow p}.y(\lambda z^p.x(\lambda.u^{(p\rightarrow q)\rightarrow p}.z)))$, but I can't see how to reach this result, when $\psi$  is given, despite my understanding why it is an inhabitant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first part I solve the exercise as stated, explaining one possible thought process that would lead you to the correct solution. In the second part, I abstract the concrete example into a method that you can follow to solve type inhabitation puzzles, and suggest some problems you can practice on. Finally, in the third part, I briefly touch upon a general *algorithm* that can solve the type inhabitation problem for the simply-typed lambda calculus.

**I.** We need to construct a term that inhabits the type $((a \rightarrow b) \rightarrow q) \rightarrow q$. Since this is a function type, we need to construct a function. It seems sensible that our lambda term would have the shape $\lambda f^{(a \rightarrow b) \rightarrow q}. X$, where $X$ itself has to inhabit the type $q$. Note that the variable $f$, with type $(a \rightarrow b) \rightarrow q$, may occur inside $X$.

Now, we just need to construct the term $X$. How can we do that?

Well, we need something of type $q$. This type $q$ is not a function type, so $X$ cannot begin with a lambda. It can only have two shapes: it's either a single bound variable, or a function application $X_1 X_2$.

Can it be a single bound variable? No! The only variable we have in scope is $f$, but $f$ has type $(a \rightarrow b) \rightarrow q$ instead of type $q$. So it must have the shape of a function application $X_1 X_2$. In fact, we have a function $f$ that, when applied to an argument $X_2$ of type $a \rightarrow b$, results in $f X_2$ of type $q$. It's a reasonable guess that our final lambda term should have the shape $\lambda f^{(a \rightarrow b) \rightarrow q}. f X_2$, where the term $X_2$ inhabits the type $a \rightarrow b$.

How can we construct such an $X_2$? Well, this is a good time to get rid of the abbreviations $a,b$: we can see that $X_2$ has to inhabit the type $((p \rightarrow q) \rightarrow r) \rightarrow (p \rightarrow r) \rightarrow r$. This is a function type, so it's a reasonable guess that $X_2$ should have the shape $\lambda g^{(p\rightarrow q) \rightarrow r}. \lambda h^{p \rightarrow r}. X_3$ for some term $X_3$ that inhabits the type $r$.

This type $r$ is not a function type, so $X_3$ will not begin with a lambda. It's either a single bound variable in the current scope, or a function application $X_4 X_5$. Let's take stock of the variables we have in scope:

```
f: (((p -> q) -> r) -> (p -> r) -> r) -> q
g: (p -> q) -> r
h: p -> r
```

We need something of type $r$, so none of these bound variables do the job immediately. Thus, we're looking to find a function application $X_4 X_5$, where $X_4$ should return something of type $r$. We have two such choices: $g$ or $h$. Which one should we go with?

Well, if we go with $h$, we'll need to choose $X_5$ to have type $p$. This looks fairly difficult, since we have nothing of type $p$ in scope.

At first glance, choosing $g$ would lead to a similar problem: we'd need to choose $X_5$ to have type $p \rightarrow q$ in this case, and we have nothing of type $p \rightarrow q$. However, we do have a lead: the type of $f$ at least ends in $q$, even though it's quite a bit more complicated than what we need. So $g$ looks a bit more promising. Let's go with it, and fix $X_4$ as $g$!

All that's left is to construct an $X_5$ of type $p \rightarrow q$. It will probably have the shape $\lambda i^p. X_6$ for some $X_6$ of type $q$.

What should $X_6$ look like? Since $q$ is not a function type, it should either be an application, or a single variable. Let's take stock of our variables again:

```
f: (((p -> q) -> r) -> (p -> r) -> r) -> q
g: (p -> q) -> r
h: p -> r
i: p
```

Well, none of our variables have the right type $q$ at this point, so we have to use a function type again. The only function that returns something of type $q$ is $f$, so we'll go with the shape $f X_7$, where $X_7$ has the type $((p \rightarrow q) \rightarrow r) \rightarrow (p \rightarrow r) \rightarrow r$.

This looks bad at first: we seemingly came back to where we started when we attempted to construct $X$ itself. But in fact the situation is not quite identical: when we started out, we only had one variable in scope, and now we have four! We need to construct a function that has type $((p \rightarrow q) \rightarrow r) \rightarrow (p \rightarrow r) \rightarrow r$, and in this new context, we can do that quite easily. Why? Because if we glance at the four variables above, we see that we can construct something of type $r$, namely the application $h i$. And since we can construct something of type $r$, we can construct functions of any type $x \rightarrow y \rightarrow r$, simply as $\lambda j^x. \lambda k^y. h i$.

At this point we can set $X_7$ to $\lambda j. \lambda k. h i$, which has the required type $((p \rightarrow q) \rightarrow r) \rightarrow (p \rightarrow r) \rightarrow r$.

Since $X_6$ had the shape $f X_7$, we now know that it is $f(\lambda j. \lambda k. h i)$.

And $X_5$ has the shape $\lambda i^p. X_6$, which is now $\lambda i^p. f(\lambda j. \lambda k. h i)$.

We keep moving back: $X_3$ was $g X_5$, which is now $g (\lambda i^p. f(\lambda j. \lambda k. h i))$, $X_2$ was $\lambda g^{(p\rightarrow q) \rightarrow r}. \lambda h^{p \rightarrow r}. X_3$, which is now $\lambda g^{(p\rightarrow q) \rightarrow r}. \lambda h^{p \rightarrow r}. g (\lambda i^p. f(\lambda j. \lambda k. h i))$, and our final term had the shape $\lambda f^{(a \rightarrow b) \rightarrow q}. f X_2$, which now becomes $$\lambda f^{(a \rightarrow b) \rightarrow q}. f (\lambda g^{(p\rightarrow q) \rightarrow r}. \lambda h^{p \rightarrow r}. g (\lambda i^p. f(\lambda j. \lambda k. h i))),$$
a closed lambda term of type $((a \rightarrow b) \rightarrow q) \rightarrow q$, the one that we sought.

**II.** How could we summarize the heuristics that we followed to obtain the solution in the previous section?

1. Let the types guide you! When you're trying to construct a term of function type $a \rightarrow b$, you'll almost always want to start with a $\lambda x^a$.
2. Take stock of what you have in scope. When you're trying to construct a term of non-function type $b$, you cannot start with a $\lambda$, so take stock of the variables you have, and see if you can combine them using applications to get something of type $b$.
3. When you have multiple choices, use common sense to try the most promising, least redundant ones first. E.g. if you're looking for something of shape $X_1 X_2$, you don't have to consider the shape $\lambda x.X_3$ for $X_1$. If it had that shape, you could perform the $\beta$-reduction/substitution and have $X_3[x:=X_2]$ instead.

The rest is practice. The problem above is quite difficult, so I advise you start practicing much simpler ones, until you get the method down. E.g. can you apply the method to inhabit the types below:

1. $(A \rightarrow A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow A \rightarrow B$;
2. $(A \rightarrow (B \rightarrow A) \rightarrow B) \rightarrow A \rightarrow B$;
3. $((B \rightarrow A) \rightarrow B) \rightarrow ((B \rightarrow B) \rightarrow A) \rightarrow B$?

**III.** Is there an *algorithm* for deciding when a type of the simply-typed lambda calculus is inhabited?

Yes! Through the Curry-Howard isomorphism, terms of type $T$ in the simply-typed lambda calculus correspond to proofs of the proposition $T$ in the implication-only fragment of Intuitionistic Propositional Logic.

Provability in intuitionistic propositional logic is decidable: in fact, there are algorithms which find such proofs. One of the best such algorithms is proof search in Dyckhoff's [LJT sequent calculus](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Efp//courses/atp/cmuonly/D92.pdf). You can learn more about sequent calculi on the [Logitext website](http://logitext.mit.edu/tutorial), and use their [online implementation of the LJT calculus](http://logitext.mit.edu/Intuitionistic/main) to decide which types have inhabitants. At this stage, this won't help you find inhabitants directly: your book does not fully cover how to translate between sequent calculus proofs, natural deduction proofs and lambda calculus terms until Chapter 7.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! Thank you very very much!!! Grateful till the bottom of my heart for your answer! I will look up chapter 7 too and the links.